# String catalog has no effect

Tags: swiftui, localization, string-catalog

We recently started localizing a SDK that we built, using the new string catalog. It contains a few views with text elements that I want to localize.

When building the SDK, the catalog is correclty filled with all the strings from `Text` elements in the SDK. Every string in the catalog is translated as I expect and reviewed. The SDK has the correct languages set in the project settings. Yet, in the previews, localized strings never work.

We tried:

- Changing the default language's translation has no effect
- Changing the translated language and setting the preview environment to "en" has no effect
- Changing the text element changes the key but the associated translation are never used.

We use this SDK in another app that has its own view and doing the same in this project effectively translates the strings.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I had problems where entries in the catalog for the default language were marked as "new" or "needs_review" and then the translations were not used. Open the string catalog as source code and see if there are entries like this. Change those pieces of text, "new" and "needs_review" to "translated" and then rebuild and see if that helps.